# Use OpenCV to receive from Gstreamer

Tags: opencv, tcp, raspberry-pi, udp, gstreamer

Mac:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("tcpclientsrc host=129.31.224.100 port=8888 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! "
                                 "videoconvert ! appsink");
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        printf("=ERR= can't create video capture\n");
        return -1;
    }
```

RPi:

```
gst-launch-1.0 wrappercamerabinsrc ! video/x-raw, 
framerate=30/1, width=1280, height=720, format=RGB ! 
videoconvert ! vtenc_h264 ! h264parse !  
rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! 
tcpserversink host=129.31.224.100 port=8888
```

The error message is:

```
VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_AVFoundation (filename)): raised unknown C++ exception!

=ERR= can't create video capture
```

The thing I want to achieve is to read frames from gstreamer by using OpenCV.

The above command works in command line, but not working in C++ code.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`cap.open (const String &filename, int apiPreference)` from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#af3b71a7c0c459704ed75568a01290457) could be what you are looking for.

You would need `CAP_GSTREAMER` (from [this list](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d)).

I would post this as a comment, but i dont have the reputation.